# Uncontrolled child component with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create a reusable component that is an uncontrolled input. Normally this works fine, but I cannot get it to work with `styled-components` applied to the child component (`value` returns `undefined`).

```
class Parent extends Component {
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(this.firstName.value)
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <UncontrolledInput
            defaultValue={'fish'}
            inputType='text'
            name='firstName'
            inputRef={(element) => {this.firstName = element}}
          />
          <button type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}


const StyledInput = styled.input`
  border: 3px solid;
`;

const UncontrolledInput = (props) => {
  const {name, inputType, defaultValue, inputRef} = props;
    return (
    <StyledInput
      name={name}
      type={inputType}
      defaultValue={defaultValue ? defaultValue : ''}
      ref={inputRef}
    />
  )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styled-components` wraps elements into a react component. Passing a `ref` prop to it will not give you the reference to the DOM element but to the wrapper component.

In the [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs) is described how to obtain a ref to the underlying DOM element:

> Passing a ref prop to a styled component will give you an instance of the StyledComponent wrapper, but not to the underlying DOM node. This is due to how refs work. It's not possible to call DOM methods, like focus, on our wrappers directly.
>
> To get a ref to the actual, wrapped DOM node, pass the callback to the innerRef prop instead.

So just change `ref` to `innerRef` on your `<StyledInput>`component:

```js
const UncontrolledInput = (props) => {
  const {name, inputType, defaultValue, inputRef} = props;
    return (
    <StyledInput
      name={name}
      type={inputType}
      defaultValue={defaultValue ? defaultValue : ''}
      innerRef={inputRef}
    />
  )
};
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m5zp7z43np?expanddevtools=1).